# How can I destroy the threads created by Akka (not just actors) on servlet undeploy?

Tags: servlets, akka, shutdown, spray

I'm using [a simple Spray-based servlet](https://github.com/spray/spray/tree/master/examples/spray-servlet/simple-spray-servlet-server). After deploying and running this servlet on Tomcat7 I undeploy it (and possibly deploy it again afterwards) **without** restarting the servlet container (so basically the JVM instance is preserved).

The problem is that the threads created by Akka at each servlet deploy are **not** destroyed when the servled is undeployed (i.e. when Akka shuts-down) and a **new** set of threads are created at every deploy. Thus... **leakage**.

Calling `system.shutdown()` and `system.awaitTermination()` is useless.

Is there a way of killing these threads spawned at servlet initialization?

Here is a sample log entry from Tomcat7:

`SEVERE: The web application [/...] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@68871741]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.Submitter] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$Submitter@155aa3ef]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 14, 2013 1:53:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks`

Comment: `system.shutdown()` should be the right tool for that. What's happening when you call it? What are the leaking threads doing?

Comment: The `system.shutdown()` call runs immediately and execution continues without any effect on the created threads (thery are still up and running). Invoking `system.awaitTermination()` immediately after the `system.shutdown()` call, hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Interesting, and where are the threads hanging exactly (try `jstack <pid>`)?

Comment: In addition to this you might want to check for container settings which disable the check whose message you included above: it seems that ForkJoinPool does not clear all its ThreadLocals. And please update to the latest stable Akka version, we fixed some thread leaks related to remoting recently.

Comment: My goal is not to remove the message but to remove the problem. If I remove the check that produces the message, the threads will sill be there after undeploy, right?

Comment: Did you try changing to use the thread-pool executor instead? `executor = "thread-pool-executor"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling system.shutdown() and system.awaitTermination() at ServletContextListener#contextDestroyed()? That should clear up all resources before moving on to undeploy the app.

If you're using the Scala API, I've created a PR for this: https://github.com/spray/spray/pull/787

Cheers

Tulio